# Restoring deleted file with Git after having returned to a earlier Checkout

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

I unfortunately deleted some file I tracked with Git and struggle to restore these files.

To be more detailed, I commited one file in a git repository.  Then, I added three more files to that repository and typed `git add <FILENAME>` and `git commit -m "blabla"`. I typed `git log` and had the impression that I am not tracking the files individually but the entire repository. However, I wanted to have a version control for each file. I then used `git checkout` to revert to the version when I only had commited one file with the other three files being untracked. Now, the three files are deleted.  Unfortunately, `git log` returns only the first commit and not the subsequent ones I made.

Can somebody please tell me how to restore the missing files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` show the log of entire repository. If you want to see log of only one file then use this:

`git log -- my/file/path`

You can get back the files under git by checking out the branch again. For example,

`git checkout master`

After this you will get files as commited. If you really want to go back to your first commit and have all new files that were added later as untracked then do this:

`git reset commit_hash`

After resetting you will get new files in your working directory as untracked files which you have to commit again.

Comment: I used ``git checkout`` to revert to the earliest version I had commited which contained only one file in the repository. When I now type ``git log`` I do not see the commits I made after I reverted back to the old version of the repository. Should this really be the `log of the entire repository`?

Comment: When you checked out to old commit, git knows nothing about the later commits. So if you want to see those files again then you have to checkout latest tip of your branch again, e.g. `git checkout master` assuming you are in master.